# python - merging lists from 2 text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm very new to Python. I want to take the contents of 2 text files, convert them into 2 lists, merge them together and order them from smallest to biggest.

Converting them to lists seems easy, but I can't merge properly for the ordering.

They come out like this (a list of lists instead of a single list): 
    ['[0, 4, 6, 6, 22, 23, 44]', '[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 777]']

Here's my code:

```
with open('numbers1.txt','r') as newfile1:
    list1 = newfile1.read().splitlines()
    print (list1)

with open('numbers2.txt','r') as newfile2:
    list2 = newfile2.read().splitlines()
    print (list2)

merged = []
for i in range(0, len(list1)) :
    merged.append(list1[i])
    merged.append(list2[i])
print(merged)
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to join to lists you can use simple `+` operator:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> merged = l1 + l2
>>> print(merged)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Now for sorting use python built-in [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html) function:

> Python lists have a built-in list.sort() method that modifies the list
>   in-place.
>   By default, sort() doesn't require any extra parameters. However, it
>   has two optional parameters:
>
> reverse - If true, the sorted list is reversed (or sorted in
>   Descending order)
>
> key - function that serves as a key for the sort
>   comparison

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> merged = l2 + l1
>>> print(merged)
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
>>> merged.sort(key=int)
>>> print(merged)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

### Edit

@Murray above-mentioned solution works just fine but it doesn't fit your use case since in your text files you have list alike string:

> This is numbers1.txt: [0, 4, 6, 6, 22, 23, 44] and this is numbers2.txt: [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 777] – Murray 1 hour ago

Now when you read file as `list1/list2` actually you'll get a list with one element which is a string.

```
>>> with open("numbers1.txt", "r") as f:
...     print(list1)
...     print(type(list1))
...     print(len(list1))
...     print(type(list1[0]))
... 
['[0, 4, 6, 6, 22, 23, 44]']
<type 'list'>
1
<type 'str'>
```

In order to append those numbers from file you'll need to parse them first. It can be achieved like so (depending on your exact use case final solution may vary):

```
$ cat numbers1.txt 
[0, 4, 6, 6, 22, 23, 44]
$ cat numbers2.txt 
[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 777]
$ cat test.py 
files = ['numbers1.txt', 'numbers2.txt']
merged = []

for f in files:
    with open(f,'r') as lines:
        for line in lines:
            for num in line.rstrip().strip('[]').split(', '):
                merged.append(int(num))

print(merged)
merged.sort()
print(merged)
$ python test.py 
[0, 4, 6, 6, 22, 23, 44, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 777]
[0, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 22, 22, 23, 44, 777]
$ python3 test.py 
[0, 4, 6, 6, 22, 23, 44, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 777]
[0, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 22, 22, 23, 44, 777]
```

Now let me break down this code into pieces:

1. First of all open file(s). I have done it with for loop so I don't have to repeat `with open...` every time I want to open something (It's just easier and the code is more readable).
2. Read all lines from a file. (I've assumed that your file can have more than just one line with list like string)
3. Parse each line and append to list.

   - `line.rstrip()` - remove a trailing newline
   - `.strip('[]')` - remove square brackets from string
   - `.split(', ')` - split string by comma and space to get array of string characters
   - `merged.append(int(num))` for each character parse it to int and append to list.
4. Last but not least sort list.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I get the same result when I just add the lists together. I have seen many posts on lists, but none that can fully solve my little issue.

Comment: @Murray Can you provide an example of what is in those files? I bet `list1 = newfile1.read().splitlines()` returns you nested list. That's why when you'll later add them it will be a list in list. At least that is my guess.

Comment: sounds like that could be the problem: This is numbers1.txt: [0, 4, 6, 6, 22, 23, 44] and this is numbers2.txt: [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 777]

Comment: @Murray For the future it's better to add that kind of edit into question rather than in a comment. Anyways, just to clarify your text files contains list like string right?

Comment: @Murray Does your use case require to have such format in txt file? Reason I'm asking is because if you have influecnce on how numbers are being stored in txt file it can be simplified. If not then of course it can be parsed with list like string but the code will be a bit more complex.

Comment: @Murray please look at the edit. This should work for you, also I've added a bit of explanation.

Comment: Works like a charm!. Thanks @Raoslaw

Comment: @Murray You're welcome :). If this solves your question can I get accepted answer?

Comment: Sure, sorry I'm still new to this site, but did hit the giant tick. I would mark up the score but I don't have enough reputation points as yet.